# wired shadow in transparent 3d rendered materials

Tags: rendering, materials

[image]I am new to blender. 
Basically i want to show a few materials in transparent. 
I made the surface files in Avizo/Amira and exported them as wrl files. I imported these into Meshlab to export as ply files. 
Then I imported these ply files and used vertex color paint and Transparency with 0.4 alpha in Material. When i 3d rendered materials in transparent, the transparent material shows some shadow-looking pattern as found in orange material in the attached image. 
Since I used the sunlight as light source, the pattern is not actually shadow. 
Is there anyway to get rid of this shadow-looking pattern in transparent material? Also what is this pattern problem called? so i can also look into this problem by myself in more detail. 
I also tried to show transparent material without vertex paint color but use coloring, but this did not change the rendered figure.

I appreciate your help!

Comment: How can one see anything in that image? It's too small... please post a bigger image to see what's in the orange area...

Comment: I changed the image size, Hopefully its more clear now. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: The posted image is not yet detailed enough, imho, to see well the supposedly subtle "shadow-looking pattern", but is a start. I can suppose this pattern is the darker orange when several "layers" of the mesh are overlayed in the view? Otherwise I can't see any other shadow...

Comment: Since the posted image is not showing the problem clearly, can you share the .blend file? use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and edit the resulting link into your question

Comment: Yes the darker orange is how i described the wired-shadow looking. I uploaded the blender file. The name of the orange material is ME.[<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=686" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/686/)